# Change <Span> value in JQuery with a condition

Tags: jquery

**I was wondering it this is possible in Jquery.
On page load i want to check if the value between `span id="TotalsTax1TD"` is Greater then $0.00 . If its $0.00 change it to $5.00 if its not $0.00 do nothing.**

```
<td class="v65-onepage-shippingcost-detail" align="right">
<span id="TotalsTax1TD" class="carttext colors_text" style="font-weight:bold;">$0.00</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#TotalsTax1TD').text(function(_, text){
        return text === '$0.00' ? '$5.00' : text;
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KEWE8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#TotalsTax1TD').text() === "$0.00")
        $('#TotalsTax1TD').text("$5.00"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#TotalsTax1TD').text() == '$0.00') {
        $('#TotalsTax1TD').text('$0.00');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var span = $('#TotalsTax1TD');
span.text(span.text()=='$0.00'?'$5.00':span.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    if(parseFloat($('#TotalsTax1TD').text().replace('$',''))==0){
        $('#TotalsTax1TD').text('$5.00');
    }
});
```